# How to pass context to a different view function?(Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My models.py:

```
class fields(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=18)
      link = models.TextField()
```

The link contains the hyperlink of the related name.

My views.py:

```
def index(request):
    listing = fields.objects.all()
    context ={'listing':'listing'}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',index,name="index"),
]
```

template:

```
 {% for i in listing %}
    <tr>
    <td data-label="name">{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td data-label="Quote"><button><a href ="{{ i.link}} " target="_blank">{{ i.link }}</a></button></td>
    <tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

This redirects to the hyperlink that is displayed in the template but I want to do some automation after it redirects into this link.

Now, I want to pass the context of this function which only includes the `link` to the other view function so that another view function will be:

```
def bypass_link(request):
    # get the link from above function
    # execute some selenium scripts in the link
```

The simple template to illustrate this will be:

```
{% for i in listing %}
<tr>
<td data-label="name">{{ i.name }}</td>
<td data-label="Quote"><button><a href ="{ % url 'bypass_link' %} " target="_blank">{{ i.link }}</a></button></td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show your **urls.py** and i'll answer for you

Comment: @Lewis it's done the urls.py is also there  now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `id` of the object into the url by altering the following:

**template**

```
<td data-label="Quote">
    <a href="{% url 'bypass_link' i.id %}" target="_blank">{{ i.link }}</a>
</td>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url 

url(r'^bypass_link/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.bypass_link, name="bypass_link"),
```

Then in your function you need to find the same model instance and then extract the link.

```
def bypass_link(request, pk=None):
    instance = fields.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(instance.link) # now you have your link
```

Now you have access to the link via `instance.link`

Answer (score 1):

**You can pass variable to different views in Django using [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions)**

*My example is using Django 3.2*, be sure that sessions requirement are set in `settings.py`. But by the default config, the following example should work.

```
def index(request):
    listing = fields.objects.all()
    # The session object must be json serializable, pay attention
    listing_list = [[list.name, list.i] for list in listing]
    # set the session variable
    request.session['listing_list'] = listing_list
    context ={'listing':listing}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def bypass_link(request):
    # get the link from above function
    # execute some selenium scripts in the link

   # Got the session variable
   listing_list = request.session.get('listing_list')
   # Do what you want with it here
```